# as3 - getChildByName on contact

Tags: actionscript-3

Would it be possible to have a movieclip like a pad, where when it crosses over with other movieclips on stage that have a name, it would then display the name of the movieclips it crosses over with without having to hard code any of them? I know how to code the cross/hit pad, but would it be able to tell me the getChildByName of any movieclip upon crossing? I am curious to have this automated.

Answer (score 1):

All MovieClips have a name. If you do not provide one, a name such as "instance[n]" will be generated automatically.
If you can handle the hit test part, then once you can reference the movieclip, you can just query the .name property.